x and y axis not displaying in chart created by openpyxl
I am trying to use openpyxl to automate the creation of graphs in excel. However, the charts that are being produced are not generating axes when I run the code on my machine.
I am using the example code for creating a scatter plot found here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/charts/scatter.html
My graph looks like this: scatter plot
My coworker ran the same code on their computer and it displayed correctly. Could it be an issue with the way Python is installed?
I am using Python 3.13.0 and version 3.1.5 of openpyxl although I have also tried version 3.1.2 based on an older question with no luck.
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    ScatterChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
    ['Size', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2'],
    [2, 40, 30],
    [3, 40, 25],
    [4, 50, 30],
    [5, 30, 25],
    [6, 25, 35],
    [7, 20, 40],
]

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)

chart = ScatterChart()
chart.title = "Scatter Chart"
chart.style = 13
chart.x_axis.title = 'Size'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Percentage'

xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
for i in range(2, 4):
    values = Reference(ws, min_col=i, min_row=1, max_row=7)
    series = Series(values, xvalues, title_from_data=True)
    chart.series.append(series)

ws.add_chart(chart, "A10")

wb.save("scatter.xlsx")


To be sure that the axis are displayed you can specifically enable them. See the answer to this Post in the code under the comment # Enable Axis for display. If you want to resize the plot area in the chart (because it overlaps the X and Y axis Titles and Chart Title) then use the code under the comment ### Adjust the layout to ensure enough space...
